# option pdfpagelabels is turned off (hyperref)

Tags: pdfpages

My problem when I try to build output,package hyperref warning:option pdfpagelabels is turned off (hyperref) because \thepage is undefined

---

[image]

This is my problem.I dont know how i can fix this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want find error hyperref.sty .when i want compile my style file in texstudio error  warning :option pdfpagelabels is turned of hyperref.but I downloaded hyperref Packet from Ctan and paste bin.but same error.

Comment: the warning is harmless. Ignore it.

Comment: Why ignore  I want fix this warning? Because if I ignore this warning I can't work with tex

Comment: Explain why a warning caauses you to not be able to work with latex?

Comment: it is only an information and shouldn't disturb compilation. But you can avoid it if you disable pdfpagelabels yourself `\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}` or by defining \thepage to something sensible (but it depends on your unknown class what is sensible).

Comment: thanks  Fischer but same error.Command \arctg already defined. \begin{document}.